# TwinCAT 3: Global Method call without instantiating function block in VAR-Definitions?

Tags: plc, debouncing, twincat, st

I want to use a global method to debounce digital inputs by passing the IO and the desired debounce time to the method and using the returnvalue to set the Bool-Variable.
The Method itself is working but I need to instantiate the function block for every input. I would like to further optimize by eliminating the need of instantiation.

Is there a possibility to configure the functionblock/method in order that the runtime allocates the memory and instantiates the method whenever it is being called?

```
METHOD NO : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    IN  : BOOL;
    T       : TIME;
END_VAR
VAR_INST
    _timer  : TON;
END_VAR

_timer (IN := IN, PT := T);
IF _timer.Q
THEN
    NO := TRUE;
ELSIF _timer.ET < T
THEN
    RETURN;
ELSE
    NO := FALSE;
END_IF
```

Call:

```
debouncedInput := debounce.NO(digitalInput, T#500MS);
```

where "Debounce" is the local instance of the funtion block.

Thanks in advance for constructive answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly than this is not possible.

Getting rid of initialization is only possible if you *do not* need to save the state of your method variables between cycles. In that case you could use a `FUNCTION`. Since you are using a `TON` inside your function block, the `_timer` instance needs to be available for the next cycle. This "state saving" is only possible when you use it in a `FUNCTION BLOCK`. That is also why you declared the `_timer` as a `VAR_INST`. Declaring it as a `VAR` would not work, since the timer would be re-initialized with every call to the `NO` method.

Unrelated to the question. Your `NO` method is doing the same as a call to the normal `TON` would be. Not sure why you implemented it this way, but I think you could also implement it with just a timer as follows:

```
PROGRAM Test
VAR
    timer : TON;
    digitalInput : BOOL;
    debouncedInput : BOOL;
END_VAR

timer(IN:=digitalInput, PT:=T#500MS, Q=>debouncedInput);
```

Or keeping the method

```
METHOD NO : BOOL
VAR_INPUT
    IN  : BOOL;
    T       : TIME;
END_VAR
VAR_INST
    _timer  : TON;
END_VAR

_timer (IN := IN, PT := T);
NO := _timer.Q
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was thinking that it is not possible. As I said: I was searching for a more convenient way for debouncing inputs.  
If you know of any other elegant solution let me know!
I think I will continue using the method with an instance for every input.

Comment: I suggested a better way by using only the timer. I do not think there is a way without creating some sort of function block for each input, since you need a separate timer for each input.